# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): ReferenceError: error is not defined

Tags: javascript, react-native, aws-amplify

```
//LoginScreen.js

import signIn from "amplify-communication"
    
  const LoginScreen = props => {
    function _signIn(username, password){
        const request = signIn(username, password);
        if(request.isCommited)
           console.log("User is Signed In");
        else
           console.log("Error Signing In", request.message);
        
       }
    }

// amplify-communication.js
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
export async function signIn(_username, _password) {
    try {
        var user = await Auth.signIn(_username, _password);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error Signing in');
    }
    finally {
        return {
            isCommitted: error ? false : true,
            message: error,
            payload: user
        }
    }
}
```

I have separate file for communicating with Amplify. I am returning an object with different keys.
On running the code it shows me following warnings.

1 - Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
ReferenceError: error is not defined
ReferenceError: error is not defined

2- Using an insecure random number generator, this should only happen when running in a debugger without support for crypto.getRandomValues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error` is only scoped to the `catch` block, so when you try to use `error` in the `finally` block, it's an undeclared identifier. You have the same problem with `user` on the success path.

Instead, either track that information in variables or repeat the `return` statement.

```
export async function signIn(_username, _password) {
    try {
        const user = await Auth.signIn(_username, _password);
        return {
            isCommitted: true,
            payload: user,
            message: undefined, // if you need it, otherwise remove
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error Signing in');
        return {
            iscCommitted: false,
            payload: undefined, // if you need it, otherwise remove
            message: error,
        };
    }
}
```

The thing about the random number generator sounds like it's just a warning from the package you're using about the environment in which you're running the code (e.g., that it doesn't have a strong random number generator).

---

Side note: It *can* be correct to turn errors into return values like that, but more times than not it's more correct to allow the error to propagate to the caller (and perhaps to its, caller, etc.) rather than forcing every level to check a return value to see if something worked. Again, without knowing what this function is for, that may or may not apply here, but just flagging it up.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It was a silly mistake from my side. I have incorporated your code, now the warning is gone but object attributes are undefined.

Comment: @MGD - The code above definitely will not produce `undefined` for (say) `isCommitted`. Are you sure you're consuming the promise, not trying to access the properties on the promise rather than its fulfillment value?

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I have tried to initialize a const with the return structure. When I debug, the const doesnt get initialized, it stays undefined in Try and Catch

Comment: I got it fixed, thanks for you help